# \raggedright behavior with minipage and tabbing

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, tabbing

In the following 3 examples a `minipage` with a nested `tabbing` environment is used to show several aligned lines of text. (This is part of a larger example.)

Output of pdflatex :

[image]

The first example is centered due to the `center` environment around it and shows the expected behavior. I do not understand the next two examples, however:

1. Why is the second example flushed left just because text is added before the `tabbing`?
2. Why does the `\raggedright` have to be placed before the `minipage` (as it does not have any effect when placed inside the `minipage` but before the `tabbing`)?

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{center}

     Example 1: Centered due to missing text:\\

     \begin{minipage}[t][1.5cm][t]{\textwidth}
       \raggedright % Has no influence
       \begin{tabbing}
         \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{5cm} \kill
         AAAA: \> test\\
         BBBBBBBB: \> test\\
       \end{tabbing}
     \end{minipage}

     {\raggedright Example 2: Flushed left by adding text:\\}%

     \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{\textwidth}
       \textbf{-added text-}
       \begin{tabbing}
         \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{5cm} \kill
         AAAA: \> test\\
         BBBBBBBB: \> test\\
       \end{tabbing}
     \end{minipage}

     {\raggedright Example 3: Flushed left without text by setting the minipage to \textbackslash raggedright:\\}

     \raggedright
     \begin{minipage}[t][1.5cm][t]{\textwidth}
       \begin{tabbing}
         \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{5cm} \kill
         AAAA: \> test\\
         BBBBBBBB: \> test\\
       \end{tabbing}
     \end{minipage}
   \end{center}

   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: A `minipage` is set to the width of the tabbing inside only if `tabbing` is the only contents of the `minipage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `minipage` or `parbox` results to have the width of an inner `tabbing` environment only if that `tabbing` is the only thing inside the `minipage`.

So in your example

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \textbf{-added text-}
  \begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{5cm} \kill
    AAAA: \> test\\
    BBBBBBBB: \> test\\
  \end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
```

The width of the `minipage` will be `\textwidth`. If instead you say

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tabbing}
    \textbf{-added text-}
    \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{5cm} \kill
    AAAA: \> test\\
    BBBBBBBB: \> test\\
  \end{tabbing}
\end{minipage}
```

then the result will be what you want (possibly with space missing). You can use the `varwidth` environment of the package with the same name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Example of text just to see that the centering will be correct

\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
  \textbf{-added text-}
  \begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{5cm} \kill
    AAAA: \> test\\
    BBBBBBBB: \> test\\
  \end{tabbing}
\end{varwidth}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool. I didn't know about this package.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still wonder why a tabbing environment 'overwrites' the width of the minipage. For me this is highly unintuitive and I can not find a reason why it behaves in this way. Could you perhaps point me to the relevant documentation?

Comment: It's a feature present in LaTeX since the beginning (at least of version 2). It's very useful for packing a `tabbing` environment so it can be placed in a "nonstandard" way with the help of `minipage` or `\parbox` (for instance to frame it).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting the `minipage` width to `\textwidth` and so the `minipage` is getting set to the width of the page.  You can see this if you frame it in a minipage.  If you know your longest line, then you can set the width of the `minipage` to the width of the longest line.

Using `calc` you can write:

```
  \begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{\widthof{ BBBBBBBB: test}}
    \textbf{-added text-}
    \begin{tabbing}
      \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{5cm} \kill
      AAAA: \> test\\
      BBBBBBBB: \> test\\
    \end{tabbing}
  \end{minipage}
```